# How can I clip a curve in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to work with pyqt and create a "UI". The main idea is to plot a graph/curve and clip the selected area with placing the widget (blue area) and clicking on the button: clip.

I tried to write a function `def clicked(self):`, which should change the data frame and update the curve. The idea: I am selecting an area, which creates a high (`self.hi`) and low value (`self.lo`). I am creating a new list `filtered`to select the index, which I want to drop later from my data frame. Is there a way to write a better function? How should I approach to this problem?

The .csv Date is online:
https://gigamove.rwth-aachen.de/de/download/ba5527c1f92270bc3235bfbd05c3a5d9

Best

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import glob 
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    Liste = ["BetaPinen4MSAlleParikel.csv"]#glob.glob("*.csv") 
    df = pd.read_csv(Liste[0])

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        #self. setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Spectrum analysis")
        self.initUI()
        self.hi = 0
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.l.addWidget(self.pw3)
        #Plot###########
        #self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
  
        self.curve_plot()
        self.lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.regionUpdate)
        self.pw3.addItem(self.lr)
        self.l.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.cw.setLayout(self.l)
        self.show()
    
    def curve_plot(self):
        self.curve = self.pw3.plot(MyWindow.df["Energy"],MyWindow.df["df1.1"], clickable=True)
        self.curve.curve.setClickable(True)
        self.curve.setPen('w')  ## white pen
        self.curve.setShadowPen(pg.mkPen((70,70,30), width=6, cosmetic=True))   

    def regionUpdate(self,regionItem):
        self.lo,self.hi = regionItem.getRegion()
        print(round(self.lo,2), round(self.hi,2))

    def initUI(self): #All the stuff on the window in this function
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("my first label!")
        self.label.move(50,50)
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Clip")
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.cw = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.proxy = QtWidgets.QGraphicsProxyWidget()
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pw3 = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.lr = pg.LinearRegionItem([250, 300], movable=True)

    def clicked(self):
        print(self.lo, self.hi)
        List = list(MyWindow.df.index.values)
        filtered = [x for x in List if x > self.lo and x < self.hi]
        print(filtered)
        MyWindow.df.index = MyWindow.df["Energy"]
        print(MyWindow.df)
        MyWindow.df = MyWindow.df.drop(filtered)
        print(MyWindow.df)

        self.curve.setData(MyWindow.df["Energy"],MyWindow.df["df1.1"])

        self.curve.sigPlotChanged(MyWindow.df)

def window() :
    app=pg.mkQApp()
    win= MyWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
window()
```

Comment: Using a mutable type (especially a complex data object like a dataframe) as a class attribute is usually a terrible idea. While this might not the case, if you keep doing this you might end up with unexpected results whenever you might want to create more instances of the class. Use an instance attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks for ur advice! I changed it. But there are still questions. Like: How can I change the data frame with marking the area and clicking on the button and how can I update the curve as a plot with the new data frame? :) 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time, but I found a solution.
First: I created a new instance with an attribute:
`win.curve_plot(name_df="BetaPinen4MSAlleParikel.csv")`

Second: I change the function `def clicked(self)` a bit.

```
def clicked(self):
        self.df = self.df[(self.df.Energy < self.lo) | (self.df.Energy > self.hi)]
        self.df = self.df.reset_index()
        self.df = self.df.drop(["index"],axis=1)
        self.curve.setData(self.df["Energy"],self.df["df1.1"])
```